# gdb\bfd: get child variable address or size or offset

Tags: gdb, debugging, binutils, dwarf

I'm using gdb and libbfd to retrieve global variables information from an elf file and show it.
I can get the following data from libbfd: Global Variable name, address and size.
I retrieve the type of the variables and its children using gdb and gdb\MI (ptype, whatis, -var-create & -var-list-children).

How can I get the address\size\offset from parent of all the children?

e.g

```
   type = struct {\n"
   unsigned char count;\n"
   unsigned char time;\n
   }\n
```

If a variable A of this type is in address 0x000100, I want to show that A.count is in 0x000100 with size 0x1 and A.time is in 0x000101 with size 0x1.

EDIT:
I've read that gdb can read the DWARF info, but I can't figure out how can I get this information from gdb.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's what I did eventually.
To get the **size**, I used:

```
p sizeof(A.time)
```

and to get the **address** I used:

```
p /a &A.time
```

NOTE: This only applies for variable of a size bigger then 1 byte.
To be able to get bitfields size and offset in bits, I had to recompile GDB according to the suggestion offered in nabble: [Address of bitfield element bug?](http://old.nabble.com/Address-of-bitfield-element-bug--td27357560.html#a27357560)